# Total number of valid permutations in a matrix to get a specific product

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, combinations, permutation

I have been trying to solve [this](http://codeforces.com/contest/894/problem/B) problem on codeforces. The question is that there are n rows and m columns that make a 2d matrix. We have to fill all the cells in such a way that the product of each row and each column should be equal to -1 or 1.

For simplicity let us consider this case:
n = 4 and m = 4 and product(variable k given in codeforces) = -1.

**This is what I've done:**

If the number of rows = 1 then these are the possibilities that we have to consider to get a product -1.

Irrespective of number of columns we can say that product can be -1 if we have one -1 or three -1's or five -1's or basically odd number of -1's

So the total number of permutations would be <sup>p(m,1)</sup>⁄<sub>1!</sub> + <sup>p(m,3)</sup>⁄<sub>3!</sub> + <sup>p(m,5)</sup>⁄<sub>5!</sub> + <sup>p(m,7)</sup>⁄<sub>7!</sub> + ... (m-1 if m is even else m)

where p(m,r) is the number of ways of arranging r things in m places

But when the above one is extended for matrix it becomes hard since for every shuffle in a particular column should lead to another shuffle in the next column.How to do that ?

Comment: You should probably read the [editorial](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/55884). It is easy to understand once you read it.

Comment: I haven't understood the editorial so I have asked

Comment: There can be only two elements in the matrix `1` or `-1`. If `k == -1` and `m` is odd and `n` is even (or vice versa) then one thing is for sure that satisying the constraint(`-1` in each row and column) in the problem is not possible. For the remaining cases, another thing to note is that what decides whether the product of all rows and columns will be `k (1 or -1)`.

Comment: Yes that we can see in the question it self. What I haven't understood in the editorial is why they have considered n-1,m-1 lines and how the answer is pow(2, [(n - 1) * (m - 1)]) .

Comment: This is decided by only one of the rows and one of the columns. So, we can put any number (1 or -1) in any cell except for that one row(lets assume the last row) and one column (assume last column) we have set apart to decide whether the product will be (1 or -1). Since we can put any number(1,-1) for each of (n-1)*(m-1) subgrid we have two choices either 1 or -1. Hence 2^((m-1)*(n-1)). Now for the (n-1)th row and (m-1)th column we need not do anything because whatever be the product of all (m-1) cells in the ith row we can convert it to required product (k) by putting 1 or -1 in the mth cell.

Comment: Could you please explain how you arrived at that solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160454/discussion-between-bharath-and-vishal-wadhwa).

Comment: Have a look at these discussions([1st](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/55884?#comment-396404), [2nd](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/55884?#comment-396205), [3rd](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/55884?#comment-396289))

Comment: okay thankyou  for pointing those discussions:)